# Can I skip the query class for this type of query?

Tags: codeigniter

Would the following query be considered 'injection safe' if I cast the incoming argument to an integer, or would I still need to use the query class?

```
public function get_chapters_by_course($course_id = NULL)
{
  $course_id = (int)$course_id; // is it sanitised yet?

  $query = $this->db->query("
  SELECT
    chapters.id AS id,
    chapters.chapter_order AS chapter_order,
    chapters.title AS title,
    chapters.description AS description,
    length(chapters.tutorial) AS tutorial_length,
    chapters.course_id AS course_id,
    (SELECT count(sentences.id) FROM sentences WHERE sentences.chapter_id = chapters.id) AS total_sentences,
    (SELECT user_id FROM courses WHERE id = $course_id ) AS course_owner
  FROM chapters
  WHERE chapters.course_id = $course_id
  ");

  return $query->result();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you are not skipping the query class when using ´$this->db->query()´

Comment: What if $course_id is fed a string like 'xyz'? doesn't that return 0?

Comment: There's also the PHP function `is_int()` to validate it.

Comment: It's a stringy number that gets passed so is_int() would always fail. If xyz was passed, then passing 0 wouldn't do anything except return an error (which I probably wouldn't see in production mode).